# How to use 7z to archive all the files and directories (including hidden ones) in a directory?

Tags: bash, wildcards, 7z

Because of specifics of my archiving needs I am not comfortable with solid tar.gz archives and use 7z instead.

I use the following command to do this:

```
7z a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=off ~/my/folder.7z ~/my/folder/*
```

To create an archive of everything inside `~/my/folder/` as the `~/my/folder.7z` file.

But `~/my/folder/.hiddenFolder` doesm't get into the archive then. How to fix this? Isn't `*` supposed to return all the files and folders?

Comment: You are using bash path expansion by last `*`, try removing it, 7z should archive the whole directory.

Comment: @enzotib but I don't want the directory in the archive, only what's inside it. And that's why I tagged the question for `bash` - maybe I am using "bash path expansion" a wrong way?

Comment: Had a similar problem, solved it by placing single quotes around the path. That way, the `*` is handled by 7z (and not by bash).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the contents of a single directory, an easy method is to change to it first:

```
cd ~/my/folder
7z a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=off ~/my/folder.7z .
```

What you saw is that `*` expands to the list of names of files that don't begin with a `.`. That's the documented behavior, and it's the main reason why files whose name begins with a `.` are said to be hidden (the other is that `ls` doesn't show them by default).

There's no really convenient portable way to list all files in a directory. You can use

```
~/my/folder/..?* ~/my/folder/.[!.]* ~/my/folder/*
```

but if there is no file matching one of the patterns then the pattern will remain unexpanded. In bash, you can set the `dotglob` option to avoid treating a leading `.` specially (`.` and `..` are still excluded from the matches):

```
shopt -s dotglob
7z a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=off ~/my/folder.7z ~/my/folder/*
```

In ksh, or in bash if you set the `extglob` option (or in zsh if you set the `ksh_glob` option), you can write a pattern that matches all files except `.` and `..`:

```
7z a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=off ~/my/folder.7z ~/my/folder/@(..?*|.[!.]*|*)
```

In zsh, there's a simpler way of saying that `.` must not be treated specially in a pattern:

```
7z a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=off ~/my/folder.7z ~/my/folder/*(D)
```

Answer (score 11):

#### TL;DR

```
7z a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=off ~/my/folder.7z ~/my/folder/.
```

#### More examples

Example directory structure

```
test1
├── .hidden
└── normal.txt

0 directories, 2 files
```

Try following commands

1. Root folder with all its contents.

   ```
   7za a test1_a.7z ~/test1/
   ```

   gives

   ```
       Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
   ------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
   2017-08-06 09:23:51 D....            0            0  test1
   2017-08-06 09:23:44 ....A            0            0  test1/.hidden
   2017-08-06 09:23:51 ....A            0            0  test1/normal.txt
   ------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
   2017-08-06 09:23:51                  0            0  2 files, 1 folders
   ```
2. No root folder and no hidden files

   ```
   7za a test1_b.7z ~/test1/*
   ```

   gives

   ```
      Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
   ------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
   2017-08-06 09:23:51 ....A            0            0  normal.txt
   ------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
   2017-08-06 09:23:51                  0            0  1 files
   ```
3. No root folder but hidden files are included (it's what we usually want)

   ```
   7za a test1_c.7z ~/test1/.
   ```

   gives

   ```
      Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
   ------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
   2017-08-06 09:23:44 ....A            0            0  .hidden
   2017-08-06 09:23:51 ....A            0            0  normal.txt
   ------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
   2017-08-06 09:23:51                  0            0  2 files
   ```

Comment: Yes just tested this and it is much tidier than using `shopt`.

Comment: Best answer here. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

No, `*` is not supposed to return all files. It returns only visible ones.

The easier solution is:

```
cd ~/my/folder
7z a -t7z -m0=lzma -mx=9 -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=off ~/my/folder.7z .
```

Answer (score 0):

I extracted my zip archives using 7z (in Linux), I have a folder full of zips.

I have used:

```
7z x *.zip -o* to extract the zip files
```

I need to figure out: 7z a {folders from above command} -r

Keeping the above in mind, I want to use the 7z a command to create a 7z archive, but using the folder name that was created in the extraction part. 
How can that be done?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/423326)